# regarding implementation of camera in android

Tags: android

I am developing an application of android which involves saving image of camera on click of click button.Can anyone give me a guidance of how to implement camera in android??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

Comment: Hey Lie are u dere?? Whats your email id..I want to contact u on email